# Custom UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout - Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, f#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a custom `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in F#, similar to the one below in C#:

```
public class CityViewDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    #region Application Access
    public static AppDelegate App {
        get { return (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public CityViewDelegate ()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Override Methods
    public override CGSize GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return new CGSize (361, 256);
    }

    public override bool CanFocusItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var controller = collectionView as CityCollectionView;
            return controller.Source.Cities[indexPath.Row].CanSelect;
        }
    }

    public override void ItemSelected (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var controller = collectionView as CityCollectionView;
        App.SelectedCity = controller.Source.Cities [indexPath.Row];

        // Close Collection
        controller.ParentController.DismissViewController(true,null);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

I have done the following:

```
    [<Register ("CollectionViewFlowDelegate")>]
type CollectionViewFlowDelegate (handle:IntPtr) = 
    inherit UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout (handle)

    let mutable parentViewController : UIViewController = null

    member this.parent 
        with get() = parentViewController 
        and set(value) = parentViewController <- value

    override x.ItemSelected(collectionView : UICollectionView, indexPath : NSIndexPath) = 
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null)
        let controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ChatControllerLandlord") :?> ChatControllerLandlord
        controller.GetListingId <- "-L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB"
        controller.GetPartnerId <- "SWs56OIGzMdiCjSXahzDQX8zve92"
        controller.GetLandlordId <- "YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2"
        controller.GetPartnerName <- "Dan"
        parentViewController.PresentViewController(controller,true,null)
```

Next, I changed the delegate for the `UICollectionView` to the custom one I defined. This crashes with the following exception:

```
    Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[CollectionViewFlowDelegate initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400001b840
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010899012b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000116260f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108a11024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108912f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108912958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ce754c8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d0ca109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d0c9e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d4acfa1 -[UICollectionView initWithCoder:] + 107
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d0ca109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d0c9e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ce7516a -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 136
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d0ca109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d0ca2a7 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d0c9e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ce74391 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010cb8b3ff -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010cb8bd2b -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d4fb304 -[UICollectionViewController loadView] + 290
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010cb8c05c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010cb8c8b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d625441 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 89
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010cb592a3 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010cb9fb67 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3808
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010cba29a9 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 99
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d756811 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 294
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d7523c0 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions] + 155
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d752098 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 118
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010cb56dba -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010cb56a31 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1397
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000135c4efe5 -[UITransitionViewAccessibility _didCompleteTransition:] + 44
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010cb590c8 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010ca7a6c4 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 343
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010ca7ad23 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 293
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000135c8d691 -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility animationDidStop:finished:] + 118
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010ca7add7 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 473
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000135c8d691 -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility animationDidStop:finished:] + 118
    37  QuartzCore                          0x00000001198446bd _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 323
    38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000116bb51ba _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    39  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000116bbf3a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1260
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108952e39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108917462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108916889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000119aaa9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    44  UIKit                               0x000000010c9e45d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    45  ???                                 0x0000000135b45518 0x0 + 5195978008
    46  ???                                 0x0000000135b45153 0x0 + 5195977043
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a simple sample for us to reproduce your issue?